# Dropdown List in Navigation Not Showing and Centering Issue with Navigation Bar

Tags: css, navigation, center, navigationbar

I am trying to have my dropdown list show on hover, but it is working no matter what I set it's position to. I think perhaps it might be the designation of 'display' none in the nav ul ul line? Also I can't get my navigation bar to center on my page. I am a beginner at html and css so please take it easy on me =).

Here is my HTML  [and the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyPLA/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title>Yanimal Art</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header"><img src="images/yanimal.gif" alt=""></div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.aspx">Portfolio</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="drawings.aspx">Drawings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="paintings.aspx">Paintings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="digitalmedia.aspx">Digital Media</</li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="shop.aspx">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    <div id="middle"><p></p></div>

    <div id="footer">Site is Currently Under Construction</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my code:

```
    body {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#header {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 124px;
        width: 830px;
        margin-top: 60px;
}
    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul li: hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
    nav ul {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #B8B8B8;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue light;
    }
        nav ul li {
            float: left;
        }
            nav ul li:hover {
                background: #e0e0e0;
            }
                nav ul li:hover a {
                        color: #333;
                }
            nav ul li a {
                    display: block;
                    padding: 12px 50px;
                    color: #000000;
                    text-decoration: none;
            }
nav ul ul {
        background: #B8B8B8;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
}
    nav ul ul li {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: none;
            position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 15px 40 px;
                color: #000000;
        }

#middle {
    opacity: 0.93;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #121212;
}
#footer {
        opacity: 0.7;
        bottom: -40;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #484838;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a few problems but nothing major.

This is the html I changed:

```
<li><a href="portfolio.aspx">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="subNav">
        <li><a href="drawings.aspx">Drawings</a></li>
        <li><a href="paintings.aspx">Paintings</a></li>
        <li><a href="digitalmedia.aspx">Digital Media</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The css I added/changed:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li:hover .subNav { /* This allows the subNav to display block when the li is hovered on */
    display: block;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86qpx/)

**Second question** To be able to center your element with `margin: 0 auto;` you need to define a width for the element.

Or you can use `text-align: center;` on your `nav` as Danko suggested, Danko's fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vFh2/1/).

You also forgot to close one of your a tags,

```
<li><a href="digitalmedia.aspx">Digital Media</a></li>
```

**I also** recommend cleaning up your css, a bit messy.

Comment: *Second Question:* Just need to add `nav { text-align:center }` http://jsfiddle.net/4vFh2/1/

Comment: @Danko Thank you for the centered fiddle!